# Spring MVC/hibernate Form validation, not returning to form

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am currently working on some HTML form validation using Hibernate and Spring MVC.

I have applied some validation to the Enity & added the code into my controller. When submitting the form to the controller with data in the incorrect format, a error page page is displayed (500). however, I want the form to be returned to the user with the error message displayed near the incorrect field.

Entity Code:

```
 @NotNull(message="Please enter a product")
    @Column(name="product_name")
    private String productName;

    @NotNull(message="Please enter a product code")
    @Pattern(regexp="([A-Z]{2,4})-([0-9]{5})|", message="Incorrect format")
    @Column(name="product_code")
    private String productCode;
```

Controller Code:

```
    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

    // create model attribute to bind form data
    QaRaised theProduct = new QaRaised();

    theModel.addAttribute("product", theProduct);

    return "product-form";
}

@PostMapping("/saveProduct")
public String saveProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") QaRaised theProduct, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    qaRaisedService.saveProduct(theProduct);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "product-form";
    }

    return "redirect:/products/qaraised";
}
```

Stack trace from Error:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.sonya.spring.entity.QaRaised] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Incorrect format', propertyPath=productCode, rootBeanClass=class com.sonya.spring.entity.QaRaised, messageTemplate='Incorrect format'}
```

Form code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="InputPC">Product Code:</label>
<form:input required="true" type="text"  title="Product Code" path="productCode" class="form-control" id="productCodeInput" placeholder="Enter Product Code" commandName="productCode"/>
<form:errors path="productCode"/>
```

The validation here is working correctly, I simply want to redirect the user back to the form. Can anyone see anything I am missing or point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Danny

Comment: why you are calling saveProduct before validation ? try return "redirect: product-form";

Comment: Hi, want2learn. Thank yo four your response. I am under the impression the saving will not go through if any validation errors are present on the form being submitted. I will try changing the redirect but believe the same result will occur

Comment: you have to move your saving code after you check binding result.

Comment: Hi want2learn, I'm sorry I am a bit confused by your comment the guides I have been looking at throughout the day (bit of a side project, I am new to java/hibernate/sprint) are handling the save in the same way. I will look at separating them out  & see what I can come up with. The save does occur if the data being input is in the correct format.

Comment: if you have validation error, you can only detect by checking bindingResult. If you remove that check, no matter you have validation error or not code will go through. So first thing you do is check if bindingResult has errors or not, If not proceed further. Hope this helps.

Comment: Taking a quick look at this today all I needed to do was move   qaRaisedService.saveProduct(theProduct); to be above return "redirect:/products/qaraised"; your first comment was correct :) thank you, needed some sleep for my eyes to see it I guess haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but I actually had the exact same issue with the same exact coding problem you had, so in case anyone else comes across this...

@want2learn is right - you shouldn't try to save the data before making sure it is valid. Otherwise, the validator will throw an exception. Just move your saving logic down:

```
@PostMapping("/saveProduct")
public String saveProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") QaRaised theProduct, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "product-form";
    }
    qaRaisedService.saveProduct(theProduct);
    return "redirect:/products/qaraised";
}
```